# Tiered pricing based on total quantity purchased

Tags: magento2, magento-1, discount, promotions, tierprice

I am selling **note cards**, and there is **no price difference** between any of them, the same pricing structure applies to all.

What I would like to do is calculate a total based on the total quantity of cards rather than individual cards.

So, a set of `3 cards = $15` regardless of which 3 is selected. Right now, my Paypal cart only allows me to have 3 cards of the same kind.  Can I do what I want with Magento?  And, what is the pricing structure for Magento?

Is it a stand alone program or can I integrate with my current site?  See http://www.miriweiblefineart.com/notecards to see the site.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to whether Magento can do this is yes, with [Shopping Cart Price Rules](https://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/marketing/price-rules-shopping-cart.html).  There are probably other ways of doing it, like using different [Product Types](https://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-types.html) and [Tier Pricing](https://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-price-tier.html) or by using [Catalog Price Rules](https://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/marketing/price-rules-catalog.html), but the simplest way would probably be to do the following:

1. Go to Magento `Admin->Promotions->Shopping Cart Price Rules->` and click `Add New Rule`
2. Add the required information under `Rule Information`.
3. Under `Actions->Apply the rule only to cart items matching....`, click the plus sign to add a condition and in the first dropdown, select `Quantity in cart`, in the second dropdown, select `equals or greater than` and in the last text-box, enter 3.
4. Under `Actions`, change `Discount Amount` to `16.666667` and click `Save`.

The result will be that any products will go from $6/each to $5/each whenever the cart has 3 or more items in it.

---

The answer to whether it can be added to your existing site is a little more complicated, but I would say no.  Mostly because going through the trouble of creating a Magento instance just to provide that functionality, then customizing both your site and the Magento instance to work with each other is probably more trouble than it is worth.  While you could use them separately, I would recommend moving the entire site to Magento, and I think the result would be a far more robust site that makes both you and your customers much happier.